What is the meaning of 则身价大涨 in 一些印刷精美、有特色的作品则身价大涨，成了收藏品?
然而，这种影响了数代人的小人书，如今只能在北京的潘家园、护国寺等地的旧书摊上找到，一些印刷精美、有特色的作品则身价大涨，成了收藏品，甚至进了博物馆。小人书和小人书摊已成为历史的记忆。
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 20. What is the meaning of 则身价大涨?
则 is a classifier?
身价 means value? Isn't 价 enough? Why is 身 needed?
大 means big?
涨 means to go up, to grow up, to increase, to rise?
How to make all this make sense?

则 = accordingly
身价 = value/ price/ worth (身价 is a compound word; 身 means 'itself/oneself; 价 means 'price')
大 = greatly
涨 = rise (as in tide rise) = increase
则身价大涨 = Accordingly, its value greatly increases

则 -〈副〉表示因果关系(used to express cause and effect)，就，便 = "then"
身(body)价(price) - here means "worth/value"
大(big/great/vast)涨(increase) - big/great/vast increase

一些印刷精美、有特色的作品则身价大涨 - some beautifully printed and distinctive works then have their worth/value soared...


Simply a question of supply and demand:  稀罕的书籍价格会上涨!
作品则身价大涨，
works thus value big rise
thus: "in the manner or state being indicated," from Old English þus "in this way, as follows," related to þæt "that" and "this".
"the manner or state being indicated" is here: 只能在北京的潘家园、护国寺等地的旧书摊上找到
然而，
However,
这种影响了数代人的小人书，
this kind of children's book influenced generations,
如今只能在北京的潘家园、护国寺等地的旧书摊上找到，
nowadays they can only be found at second-hand book stalls in Beijing's Panjiayuan, Huguo Temple, etc.
一些印刷精美、有特色的作品则身价大涨，
the value of some exquisitely printed, characteristic examples has thus risen enormously,
成了收藏品，
to become collector's objects,
甚至进了博物馆。
(and) have even been put on display in museums.
小人书和小人书摊已成为历史的记忆。
Children's books and children's book stalls have faded into history.

Given their current popularity and value, I don't think ‘have faded into history’ (= relegated to history and forgotten) is what’s meant here; it’s more like ‘have become mementos of history’ (= items that link us to our history and conjure up images of the past, roughly like ‘antiques’).

则:
I don't agree with the other answers.
In your example, 则 does not express causality. It is an adverb and means "moreover". It emphasizes that some picture-story books are even more precious than others, so that they are worth more in terms of money.
身价:

net worth of sb.(usually a billionaire)
value or price of sth.

In your example, 身价 takes the second meaning. But mostly, the word is used to describe people, especially wealthy people, like Elon Musk.
大涨:
You are correct about this. 大 means big or huge. 涨 means increase or rise.
